# Can you compile JS code using V8 and feed that directly to Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, compilation, v8

I'm looking for a way to protect some javascript code from reading/modifying. I know many people consider that impossible, but still...

From what I see the Chrome's V8 engine does a number of optimizations when it sees JS code, probably compiles it (?) and then runs it.

So I'm wondering is it possible to use V8's C++ api to compile the JS code into machinecode/chromecode and then feed that directly into Chrome (I don't care about other browsers)?
Supposedly it will not only be faster, but also non-humanly readable, something like ASM.

Is this possible?

WebAssembly is doing this thing so I don't understand why we can't do it with JS code.
There's also EncloseJS and pkg that are doing a very similar thing.

Comment: *"I know that's considered impossible, but still..."* :P

Comment: @Li357 what I meant to say was "I know many people consider it impossible, but it's not" :) If webassembly is doing it, then there's clearly a way, I just don't know if anybody has figured out a way to do the same for JS.

Comment: Umm, it's not hard to read and modify WebAssembly code either. Code generated by encloseJS pkg can be read and modified as well.

Comment: @phihag it can, but it's the same as reading and modifying an .exe file. It's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is moving some of the logic from JavaScript into C++ and compiling that into NodeJS native modules (that's possible for Electron apps).

It works pretty good, it's very fast, the source is... as protected as it can get, but you may need to worry about cross-platform issues, also compiling/linking can be a bit of a pain, but other than that it's great.

Answer (score 4):

V8 developer here. No, it is not possible to compile JavaScript ahead of time and send only the compiled code to the browser. V8 (and other virtual machines like it) *contain* compilers, but they cannot be used as standalone compilers to produce standalone binaries.

*In theory*, you could compile JavaScript to WebAssembly -- any two turing-complete programming languages can in theory be compiled to each other. As far as I know, no such compiler exists today though. One big reason for that is that performance of the end result would be horrible (see the discussion with Andreas Rossberg for details); so considering that browsers can execute JavaScript directly, people have little reason to develop such a thing. (It would also be a large and difficult task.)

As for your stated goal: your best shot at making JavaScript code unreadable is to minify it. In fact, that is effectively just as good as your idea to generate assembly, because disassemblers exist that turn assembly back into minified-like higher-level language code; they cannot reconstruct variable names or comments (because that information is lost during compilation), but they can reconstruct program logic.

Comment: Thanks. I still think I'm missing something though. Is it correct that Chrome can run "native code" and not only optimized javascript? And if so can this "native code" perform instructions to manipulate the DOM, or is it only limited to math operations?

Comment: And I actually got a far better solution than minifying the code. Since this is a nodejs app, I rewrote parts of it in C++, so the critical stuff is no longer plain text. I was just wondering if that's the only option. Sure it can be disassembled, but this is good enough.

Comment: Chrome can execute JavaScript and WebAssembly. I don't know what "native code" you're talking about. -- If you're talking about a node.js app, why are you asking about Chrome?

Comment: The case in point is an electron app - so it uses both nodejs and chrome. It is also widely considered impossible to protect, but if you move part of the logic in node C++ modules, it's perfectly possible. So I was wondering if a similar thing can be done with Chrome. But I didn't ask the right question :) So If there's no "native code" in Chrome and it can only run Webassembly and JS, yet webassembly is limited to math operations only, then... yeah :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

WebAssembly is not doing that. And no, it's not possible either. The web is supposed to be both browser- and hardware-independent.

Moreover, a language like JS would *not* be faster if compiled offline -- it only is anything close to fast because it is dynamically compiled and optimised, taking dynamic profile information into account.

Comment: Well today I compiled a bunch of webassembly stuff and it's quite non-humanly readable :) 
I don't know what you mean by "webassembly is not doing that" - it's precisely that :)

Comment: But it's not machine code. The VM still has to compile it to machine code in your browser.

Comment: this is how it looks like: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/14653/assembly-output.png
If c++ code can be compiled into this, then I'm trying to understand why JS cannot be. It seems to me like nobody bothered to write the tool for this task yet. And not that it's not possible.

Comment: Compiling JS to Wasm first and from there into native code later would would lose all dynamic optimisations. The result will easily be 10-100x slower. Moreover, you would have to ship half a JavaScript VM with every script, which would blow it up to megabytes of code. JavaScript is simply not designed for static compilation.

Comment: Sorry I'm stupid and I still don't understand. The webassembly native code is meant to perform mostly math calculations - and it's doing it tens of times faster than standard JS - event with all its dynamic optimisations, and so on. That's why it exists - speed. And you don't know what language was used to generate this webassembly native code - it could be c++, rust, anything. How come if it was javascript, it becomes 100x slower? The only possible problem I see is if the native code is limited to only certain operations - like lack of DOM. Speed is absolutely not the problem here.

Comment: JS requires dynamic optimisation to be fast (especially for math, because you first need to find out all the types, which you cannot statically for JS). Simply speaking, a JS VM first compiles a JS program to very slow code, profiles it while running, and then recompiles it to something more optimised, often over and over again, while the program is still running. For that, it needs to have the original JS program or something equivalent. An offline compiler could likewise only generate very slow code initially, but with no way of recompiling and optimising it while running.

Comment: That's ok. But even with all the theoretically possible optimizations one can do on the JS code, it will still run 10x times slower than the native code equivalent. That's not my statement, this is what the browser devs are saying. So this discussion about js optimizations is really a nonsense.  Its performance is a joke compared to native code. I've researched the topic long enough and the reason I'm posting here is to hopefully get a response from devs with deep V8 experience that can explain how the "Script::Compile" function works, what it does, is it limited in API capabilities, etc.

Comment: Two corrections here: (1) optimized compiled JS code is about as fast as C++ or whatever you call "native". It is not "a joke". (2) Andreas Rossberg is a "dev with deep V8 experience", he knows what he's talking about, and it's not "nonsense". Please be respectful of the people who are spending their time to help you.

Comment: No disrespect meant, sorry if it seemed like this :)

Comment: Yet the claim that "console.log('hi');" compiled to webassembly will be 100 times slower than "printf('hi');" compiled to webassembly is quite strange and lacking argumentation. So I hope you understand where I'm coming from.

Comment: I don't see anyone making claims about "console.log". Measuring and comparing performance is tricky -- no one-line program will give you results that are representative of real, large apps. Nobody knows just how slow JavaScript compiled to WebAssembly would be for typical applications because nobody has tried it, but 10x-100x slower than running it on V8 directly is a reasonable estimate, I think.

Comment: This comment thread is golden, thank you @jmrk!